# Getting UnicodeEncodeError while loading data from DynamoDB in python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

The error I encountered while taking data from DynamoDB;

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 1761: character maps to

Codes;

```
self.db = boto3.resource(
        'dynamodb',
        region_name=Config.AWS_DB_REGION_NAME,
        aws_access_key_id=Config.AWS_DB_ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=Config.AWS_DB_SECRET_KEY
)
self.tableName = "test"

queryAll():
    self.actionTable = self.db.Table(self.tableName)

    query = self.actionTable.scan(
        ProjectionExpression='id, cityName, title, lat, lng',
        FilterExpression=Attr("type").eq("attraction")
    )

    return query

venues = queryAll()

print("Found Records: {}\n".format(str(venues['Count']) + "/" + 
str(venues['ScannedCount'])))
founds = list()

if venues['Count']:
 for i, item in enumerate(venues['Items']):
    if "lat" in item:
        founds.append(
            {
                "id": item["id"],
                "title": str(item["title"]),
                "location": str(item['lat']) + "," + str(item['lng'])
            })
print(founds)
Items = venues['Items']
exit()
```

Comment: please change your title, it's too filthy. can you please provide full error stack please.

Comment: @Mr.J english is not too good :(

Comment: now, looks good, please provide me error stack in details.

Comment: @Mr.J, I can not write the data I added to the founds variable

Comment: which line from above code is causing error? i need error details not source code or input

Comment: @Mr.J, print(founds)

Comment: Basically, you're running into an encoding error, which isn't related to DynamoDB. Looks like your current encoding settings do not specify how to encode a particular character. You could try changing the encoding to 'utf-8', but it may not help as you need to know the exact encoding of your data and output it according to that encoding.

Comment: @ForceBru, when i am running sorry i still get "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 1838: character maps to <undefined>" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solve the problem with this function

```
.encode('ascii','ignore').decode()
```

using;

```
"title": str(item["title"]).encode('ascii','ignore').decode(),
```